# Excel copy activity error : Wrong local Signature

Tags: excel, azure-data-factory

A system that we track sends us data in excel format (only format available).  After an update to the system, we started getting errors with a pipeline that treats this excel (it had been working for years).  It seems the format of the excel file has changed and the excel connector cannot open this "new" file.  Nothing has changed in the file, same data schema, number of sheets, ...

The error is:
Encrypted excel file 'Name of file.xlsx' is not supported, please remove its password. Wrong Local header signature: 0x9EB

When opening the file on my pc and just resaving it, it can now pass in the pipeline without the error.

I unzipped the xlsx and tried to compare all the xml files with the resaved excel xml files and don't see anything related to this error (encryption)

Does anyone been confronted with this kind of error ?